# Java -  printing lines from buffered reader 

Tags: java

I'm writing an `InputStream` that supplies lines from a file in constant intervals. I used `BufferedReader` before, but ran into buffering issues with it (wasn't getting anything until the entire file was read), and speed isn't an issue anyways (the intervals are something like every second, or every half second - along those lines). Is there a class with a `readLine` method like in `BufferedReader`, except unbuffered?

(Edit: I just checked - my class seems to work, apparently the problem was with the output)

Here's the code where I used the stream (`OnlineDataSimulator`). I already checked, the stream does exactly what I want, so apparently I'm doing something wrong with the output. (The actual problem is, I want output to occur every X milliseconds - X being the second parameter to `OnlineDataSimulator`. What happens when I run this code is, that I first get an X*lines wait and then the entire output at once instead.)

```
        System.out.println("Testing:");
        PrintStream fout = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("testfile"));
        for(int i=0; i<20; ++i) {
            fout.println(i);
        }
        fout.close();
        BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new OnlineDataSimulator("testfile",250)));
        String line;
        while((line=fin.readLine())!= null){
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.flush();
        }
        fin.close();
        (new File("testfile")).delete();
```

Comment: You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Here's one usage [example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/241.html)

Comment: Just flush the output when you want it to arrive at the receiver.

Comment: I'm trying that, but somehow it doesn't work. I posted example code now (the stream itself behaves as I expect), can you please explain to me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

Try it this way.... This worked for me..

```
File f = new File("path");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String s = null;

while ((s=br.readLine())!=null)
    {

           System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: only FileReader which worked for me.  Plain text file in resources directory, building with gradle.  Can either load the properties file, as standard, or, using above, actually read it in as a String.  Which seems mundane until you try and do it.  Because it works when building and running it should also work with a distributed JAR or fat JAR or uber JAR.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other non-buffered option. 
A solution would be to write your own Reader which has a InputStreamReader as an underlying stream and in the readLine() method you should call read() of the underlying input stream reader until "\n" is found. Aggregate all these and return them as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a real buffer but want to use the functionality of `BufferedReader` you could initialize it with buffer size 1. As you commented that speed isn't an issue maybe is the most reliable solution.

```
new BufferedReader(reader, 1)
```

[public BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader%28java.io.Reader,%20int%29)

and you can check the `readLine()` method source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.readLine%28boolean%29), in case you want to implement your own.

Comment: I had the same idea, but I wonder if it wouldn't have issues with empty lines (the `\n` would be buffered and the empty line would only be returned when the next line is read). Worth trying, though.

Comment: the `\n` isn't buffered... if you check the source code you will see that this is a terminator for `readLine`, in this case (that just `\n` is found), the `StringBuffer` being use to store the line is empty, returning an empty string to the invocation. Meaning, empty lines are returned as empty strings.

Comment: Damn, still doesn't work. Is FileReader maybe already buffered?

Comment: @Cubic: are you trying to modify the file after start reading it and expecting the read process to read the modification?

Comment: @Cubic: does your stream send the line terminator at the end of each line?

Comment: It does. I get the correct output, just the delays aren't where I want them to be.